# How to handled a “Java Web Start Launcher has stopped working” issue?

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, java

Someone in finance (Windows Pro 64-bit 1709) is trying to run BARX but after loading a bit I get the error ”Java Web Start Launcher has stopped working.” When I look at the event viewer I get a few things.

```
Faulting application: jp2launcher.exe, version 11.151.2.12
Faulting module name: MSVCR100.dll, version: 10.0.40219.325
Exception code: 0x40000015
faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\jp2launcher.exe
faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\MSVCR100.dll
```

What I've tried so far-

Uninstalled and reinstalled 32 and 64bit versions of Java.
I read somewhere that `MSVCR100.dll` is part of Visual C++ 2010, so I removed and reinstalled both the 32 and 64bit versions.
I also copied the DLL from another windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

In the end all I had to do was copy a healthy `MSVCR100.dll` from another machine into: `C:\Windows\System32\ and into C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\`